# Django Pagination Issue

Tags: django, pagination, django-pagination

I wanna show pagination for my objects that has specific foreign key, with help of documentation, I'm using this:

```
def baslik_handle(request, title):
    baslik, created = Baslik.objects.get_or_create(title=title)
    entryler2 = Entry.objects.filter(baslik=baslik).order_by('timestamp')
    paginator = Paginator(entryler2, 10)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        sayfalar = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        sayfalar = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        sayfalar = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    ctx = {'entryler2':entryler2, 'sayfalar':sayfalar}
    return render(request, "baslik/tek.html", ctx)
```

for html:

```
{% for entry in entryler2 %}

        {{ entry }}<br>

{% endfor %}



<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if sayfalar.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ sayfalar.previous_page_number }}"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
             {{ sayfalar.number }} / {{ sayfalar.paginator.num_pages }}
        </span>


        {% if sayfalar.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ sayfalar.next_page_number }}"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

after all this pagination is not working. It just calculate the page numbers and don't separate objects to pages.
For instance I have 26 "Entry"s that have same Baslik foreign key. When I look to its pages, it just list all 26 "Entry"s in all 3 pages. What's wrong with my code? What should I do to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced this:

```
{% for entry in entryler2 %}
```

to this:

```
{% for entry in sayfalar %}
```

and it's fixed.